# Use a phone as a mic

Tags: windows, gratis, android, audio, ipad-app

I want to use phone (android) or iPad as a microphone on my Windows computer and need a free program to do that. Note that I need realtime microphone, not an audio recorder.

I found only [EZ Mic](https://www.ez-mic.com/) and it worked, but it's not free. Is there any free analogue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source option: [Microphone](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.bitplane.android.microphone/).

From the description:

> This microphone just feeds audio from the phone's mic right out of its
>   speaker, which means you get a horrible screeching feedback noise.
>
> However, plug the thing into your computer with a male to male
>   headphone jack and your phone becomes a PC mic.

Comment: Ooooops.. Nice idea, but actually I need it to work via wifi as I have no working mic jacks.